# unable to run command as sudo in php (CentOS 7)

Tags: centos, sudo, php

I need to run a sudo command from a PHP script in CentOS 7, but I am getting an error:

> sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

I have edited my sudoers file with the following lines, as others have advised:

1. don't require tty:

   `Defaults:apache     !requiretty`
2. Set no password for apache user:

   `apache  ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /path/to/app, /path/to/app2`

(I have double-checked that these paths are correct). My errors persist. Any thoughts?

Comment: Is that the *only* sudoers line for apache? Could it be hitting another rule?

Comment: It is the only line, yes

Comment: You would better find another way of doing that. Apache has another user for security reasons, giving `sudo` to Apache is a *very bad idea*.

Comment: ```apache = NOPASSWD: /path/2/app, /path/2/app2 ``` could you try this?

Answer (score 1):

This line does not give `sudo` permissions to app and app2:

```
apache  ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /path/to/app /path/to/app2
```

What the above line does is give sudo permissions to run `/path/to/app`, only if you also pass a single argument to it of `/path/to/app2`. To specify multiple commands, they need to be separated by a comma:

```
apache  ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /path/to/app, /path/to/app2
```

Comment: ah, that was just a typo in my post, which I've now changed